# Fatal Exception error Android

Tags: java, android, exception, xmpp

I am trying to connect to an open fire server through `XMPPClient` from my android device. i am running the `Network thread` separately on `Async-Task` .

**The issue Is**

**1-** My code is not allowing me to connect to an openfire server, but it connects with gmail server easily. is i am missing some thing in my code?

**2-** the moment when my system get connects with any server, say gmail, it crashes and i get following error in my `LogCat`

**Error**

```
03-07 12:29:57.085: W/dalvikvm(26662): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a95210)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at com.example.test.NetworkOperation.doInBackground(NetworkOperation.java:42)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at com.example.test.NetworkOperation.doInBackground(NetworkOperation.java:1)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-07 12:29:57.115: E/AndroidRuntime(26662):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

**Here is the code that is running in Async Task**

```
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private XMPPClient xmppClient;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String host = "talk.google.com"; //getText(R.id.host);
        String port = "5222";  //getText(R.id.port);
        String service = "gmail.com"; //getText(R.id.service);
        String username = "hassaan.rabbani@gmail.com"; //getText(R.id.userid);
        String password = "**********"; //getText(R.id.password);

        // Create a connection
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port),service);
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

        try {
            connection.connect();
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
            xmppClient.setConnection(null);
        }
        try {
            connection.login(username, password);
            Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

            // Set the status to available
            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
            xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + username);
            xmppClient.setConnection(null);
        }

      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }
  }
```

Am i missing something? n?

Comment: The only think I don't currently like in your code is the double `try` block. If the first one fails, the second one still executes.

Comment: in the second try block, i got uncaught exception after execution of this line xmppClient.setConnection(connection);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are never assigning anything to your xmppClient variable, therefore it is null.

You aren't hitting it in the first try as that one is succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    String host = "talk.google.com"; //getText(R.id.host);
    String port = "5222";  //getText(R.id.port);
    String service = "gmail.com"; //getText(R.id.service);
    String username = "hassaan.rabbani@gmail.com"; //getText(R.id.userid);
    String password = "**********"; //getText(R.id.password);

    // Create a connection
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
            new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port),service);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
    if(xmppClient != null){
    try {
        connection.connect();
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        connection.login(username, password);
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
        xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
        xmppClient.setConnection(null);
    }
    }else{
        Log.d("Connection", "check your xmppClient");
    }

  return null;
}
```